# Broadcast receiver not receiving

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adb

I want to make a broadcast and my Receiver should receive the broadcast, but it is not working.
I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="utilities.dip.com.checkbattlevelstackof">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <service
        android:name=".YourService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </service>

    <!-- Receivers -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The receiver is:

```
package utilities.dip.com.checkbattlevelstackof;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;



public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";
    public static final String ACTION_BOOT = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_BOOT)) {
            // This intent action can only be set by the Android system after a boot
            Log.d(TAG,"Received boot event");
            Intent monitorIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
            monitorIntent.putExtra(YourService.HANDLE_REBOOT, true);
            context.startService(monitorIntent);
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG," Action received : " + intent.getAction());
        }
    }
}
```

When I am making a broadcast I am not getting any log:

```
platform-tools $ ./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -n utilities.dip.com.checkbattlevelstackof/utilities.dip.com.checkbattlevelstackof.BootReceiver
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] cmp=utilities.dip.com.checkbattlevelstackof/.BootReceiver }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

What is the mistake ?

Comment: remove the if statement. when u set specific intent-filter in manifest u don't need to check it again inside class. and also you don't need to add category for receiver.

Comment: Done, nothing happened. See I also have an else, just to check. No log generated.

Comment: what about requesting permission? (if you are on api > 22)

Comment: I have already provided permission in manifest. And I am using command line to fire the adb command. There is no error. Is there anything I need to add ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have declared  outside  in your manifest. It basically should look like this:

```
<application
        .....
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Also while checking the action string especially for the default Android actions, don't use your own constant. Instead of using ACTION_BOOT constant use "Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED"

Answer (score 1):

Add receiver & service inside application tag.